# Natural example to "negative $\times$ negative = positive"

Tags: soft-question

Please help me to find some natural example of the meaning of a negative $\times$ negative = positive, except velocity, distance etc in physics.

Simplest example to mind is $$a(t) \times v(t)$$ but I am looking for a something else. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: `find some natural example of` Before asking about multiplication, it helped if you gave an example of what you would consider a "*natural example*" of a negative number, say for example $-1$.

Comment: @dxiv I'm sure the question can be reduced to your question in any case.

Comment: @Khosrotash Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 10):

If your company loses $\$7$ per year, then $3$ years ago, your company was $\$21$ richer.

Comment: (This is a resurrected deleted answer that I liked. I would give credit, but I'm guessing the original asker didn't want to be associated with this answer for whatever reason.)

Answer (score 3):

A square with side $L$ has area

$$L\cdot L=L^2$$

Then the area of the rectangle with sides $L-a$ and $L-b$ is

$$(L-a)\cdot (L-b)=L^2-La-Lb+ab$$

therefore

$$(-a)(-b)=ab$$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On the plane with a coordinate system, "negative" means a rotation of $180^\circ$ around the origin and possibly a change of the magnitude, given by the multiplication by the absolute value of the negative quantity.

Then "negative $\times$ negative" means a double rotation of $180^\circ$, that is, no rotation at all, and possibly a change of the magnitude, given by the multiplication by the product of the absolute value of the two negative quantities.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the primary reason that negative $\times$ negative $=$ positive is that this yields attractive algebraic behaviour.  So, this probably does not qualify as *natural* as you wished.

That this, and much else of mathematics, often works well in the real world has often been discussed.  Eugene Wigner wrote an article on the subject: [The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Mathematics in the Natural Sciences (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unreasonable_Effectiveness_of_Mathematics_in_the_Natural_Sciences)

Others have given some examples of how the rule fits some real life situations but there are cases where negative results don't make sense.

Consider that you need to travel $100km$ and you expect to be able to travel at $60km/h$ hence $1km$ per minute.  So, you expect to complete the journey in $100$ minutes.  Suppose that you fail to achieve the $60km/h$ but only achieve $30km/h$.  You might calculate the speed you need for the rest of the journey to arrive on time.  A little calculation gives this formula: $60 \times (100 - \frac{1}{2}t) / (100 - t)$ where $t$ is the time so far in minutes.  As you approach the target time, $t = 100$, the required speed explodes and (informally) is infinity at $t = 100$.  What happens after $t = 100$?  The formula gives negative values.  It suggests that if you drove backwards then you would complete the journal in negative time.  Negative speed $\times$ negative time $=$ positive progress - nonsense.

So, you need to consider whether negative numbers make sense in your model.  Sometimes they will and sometimes they won't.  For example, if you are planning a flight then be careful about negative altitudes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify the question to show that $(-1)\times(-1)=1$ since positive scalar multiplication in physics is always easy to explain in terms of intensity.

So, we just need to think in the real involution $-:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and then interpreting in any physical context why under the composition it has order $2$. The minus sign almost always mean "backward" (but you have examples of that in velocity and distance) other times this involution means "lose", for example, if you have a fluid, you can put a positive sign if you are gaining fluid volume and put a negative sign if you are losing (regardless the direction of the fluid). Suppose you are losing a lose of some fluid, then you are gaining that amount of fluid. (It works also with gaining or losing energy)

I hope this viewpoint may help you.